# Eclipse 3.7 Classic Nightmare - ADT Installation

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've been trying to install the ADT for Eclipse Classic 3.7 to no avail.

From what I've seen on searches, the general consensus seems to be to update the software, but alas I cannot do that, either.

**BELOW**: An example of the error message received when trying to update Eclipse, or when attempting to install from a web location.

> Some sites could not be found.  See
>   the error log for more detail. Unable
>   to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/content.xml.
>   Cannot assign requested address:
>   JVM_Bind

I followed the troubleshooting recommendations of Google/Android's developer section, and attempted to install ADT via archive.

**BELOW**: The resulting error from attempting to install via archive.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486) requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Now, from what I hear, the inability to update/install via Internet seems to be a proxy-related issue, however I don't believe that I'm under any such thing (I'm just using my computer connected to my home network for this). I'm using the most up-to-date versions of anything I can think of (ADT, Eclipse, SDK Tools etc).

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, and am using the 64bit version of Eclipse Classic.

Comment: try to use http instead of https.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that to no avail. Apologies. :(

Comment: While I'm at it, I should also mention that the JavaEE version of Eclipse is able to install ADT from the archive - but it's still unable to update, just like Classic.

Answer (score 1):

I am using eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and had to add the following repository (without having to check any component at all, simply add this entry) http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo in Help > Install New Software...

Then installing ADT was possible (at first I had an error, then I was able to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, with Eclipse ADT, and C/C++ (CDT) plugins,
in the OS Windows7 x64, and Ubuntu x86.

The solution is simple, and it has to do with super user rights.

In ubuntu, just:
Install eclipse from software center, and each time you want to install a new plugin open a terminal and write:
sudo eclipse

and in Windows, right click on Elipse.exe and "Run As Administator".

On Ubuntu when the plugin is installed, close the Eclipse, and then open it regularly(without sudo), so you configure if needed, the plugin (eg on ADT set location of ADB)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error dude. I suggest downloading an older version of eclipse. To be exact, 3.5. I found that information on a chines blog (which I translated with Google awesome tools :P).

Hope this helps - I'm going to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

ADT is not claimed as working with 3.7 - use 3.5/3.6, or look for Motodev Studio - Motorola's Eclipse(3.6) based IDE for android development, a bit more comfortable than pure ADT, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As @piotrpo mentions, you can use MOTODEV Studio (I'm the product manager). We tested ADT with Indigo as the milestone builds came out in June. There didn't seem to be any inherent weirdness in Indigo that prevented ADT from loading (or vice versa).

We're still working to get the Indigo version of MOTODEV Studio out the door as part of our normal release cycle, but our [2.2.2 update for Eclipse](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/download/) works with Eclipse Classic on Indigo. It has ADT, our plugins, and all the dependent plugins as a single installable unit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run eclipse as with root. **(that means type 'sudo' before eclipse) for linux distros and for windows rightclick the eclipse application and select 'run as administrator',** By using root to open eclipse I could install the plugin with with help->install new software--> and then inputing the:
*https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/*